# Не видно баннер MDTopAppBar (toolbar)

Tags: python, kivy

Непойму почему не видно цвет, текст, иконка навигационного бара на первой сцене, если совместить вместе две навигации. А на второй сцене он виден, но как-то на заднем фоне, то есть если добавить виджет лейбл с текстом вверху, то он ляжет прямо на баннер

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.scrollview import MDScrollView

KV = '''
<ContentNavigationDrawer>

    MDList:

        OneLineListItem:
            text: "Screen 1"
            on_press:
                root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                root.screen_manager.current = "scr 1"

        OneLineListItem:
            text: "Screen 2"
            on_press:
                root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                root.screen_manager.current = "scr 2"

MDScreen:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    
    MDTopAppBar:
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        elevation: 4
        title: "FID: Find Image Description"
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]
        
    MDNavigationLayout:
        
        MDScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager

            MDScreen:
                name: "scr 1"

                MDBottomNavigation:
                    #panel_color: "#eeeaea"
                    selected_color_background: "orange"
                    text_color_active: "lightgrey"
                
                    MDBottomNavigationItem:
                        name: 'screen 1'
                        text: 'Load'
                        icon: 'gmail'
                
                    MDBottomNavigationItem:
                        id: mybtn
                        name: 'screen 2'
                        text: 'Image'
                        icon: 'twitter'
                
                    MDBottomNavigationItem:
                        name: 'screen 3'
                        text: 'Text'
                        icon: 'linkedin'

            MDScreen:
                name: "scr 2"

        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
            radius: (0, 16, 16, 0)

            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                screen_manager: screen_manager
                nav_drawer: nav_drawer
'''

class ContentNavigationDrawer(MDScrollView):
    screen_manager = ObjectProperty()
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()

class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.material_style = "M3"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

Test().run()
```